# NSAttributedString displayed in UILabel wrong on iOS14

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

An NSMutableAttributedString with some attributes was correctly displayed in an UILabel up until iOS 12, but is wrong/different on iOS 14:

The string "bukskin" has two letters coloured red, the last 4 letters are underlined, correctly on iOS 12:

[image]

On iOS 14 the underlining extends beyond the end of the word for about two letters. This seems to only happen if the underlining is at the END of the string:

[image]

Dumps of the string attributes for iOS 12 and iOS 14 look identical, yet the string is displayed differently on screen in an UILabel, on iOS 14.  Am I missing something?

Dump for iOS 12 (using enumerateAttributesInRange):

```
word=bukskin attributed_word=b{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.8125 0 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 0;
}uk{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 0;
}s{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}k{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.8125 0 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}in{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
} attrs={
    NSColor = "UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}
```

Dump for iOS14:

```
word=bukskin attributed_word=b{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.8125 0 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 0;
}uk{
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600003682440; name = labelColor>";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 0;
}s{
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600003682440; name = labelColor>";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}k{
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.8125 0 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}in{
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600003682440; name = labelColor>";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
} attrs={
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600003682440; name = labelColor>";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}
```

Comment: Not the same issue. Others also found that initial versions of **iOS 14** had rendering issues with `NSAttributedString` (even though the attributes/metadata was correct). See [Strikethrough style is not rendered in iOS 14](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657015) What version of iOS 14 are you testing it against?

Comment: iOS 14.5 and 14.6. The link does contain a hint for a fix, by fiddling the baselineoffset, setting that to 0 for the entire length of the attributed string. That seems to work for me too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link in Tarun Tyagi's comment hints at a fix: setting the baseline offset to 0 for the entire attributed string. That seems to work. Right after initialising I now do:

```
[att_word addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] range:NSMakeRange(0, att_word.length)];
```

I'll file a bug with Apple.

The attributes dump now is:

```
word=bukskin attributed_word=b{
    NSBaselineOffset = 0;
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.8125 0 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 0;
}uk{
    NSBaselineOffset = 0;
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000506f00; name = labelColor>";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 0;
}s{
    NSBaselineOffset = 0;
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000506f00; name = labelColor>";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}k{
    NSBaselineOffset = 0;
    NSColor = "UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.8125 0 0 1";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}in{
    NSBaselineOffset = 0;
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000506f00; name = labelColor>";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
} attrs={
    NSBaselineOffset = 0;
    NSColor = "<UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600000506f00; name = labelColor>";
    NSLigature = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}
```